# Got 2 plus points from downvote

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, down-votes

An answer of mine was downvoted and instead of decreasing my rep by 2 points it increased by 2 points. The downvoter removed his downvote. I did a recalc and the 2 points were removed from my rep.

This looks like a bug.

Comment: On what site? What you see in the reputation tab of your profile page?

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: On Stackoverflow.com. I didn't see anything in the reputation tab. Maybe I did not wait long enough.

Comment: Hmm.. where exactly did you see that +2 of reputation?

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd: On the top bar of the Stackoverflow site and on my profile site.

Comment: Hmm.. maybe race condition in the new reputation calculation system. OK, I leave it for mod/dev to investigate. :)

Comment: On which user?  On SO I see no recalc that lowered your reputation in the past several days...I do however see a recalc that *increased* your reputation, after a post which had a downvote was deleted.

Comment: @NickCraver: I am talking about this user: juergen d. I noticed the decribed behaviour while answering to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006171/error-column-count-doesnt-match-value-count-at-row-1

Comment: @NickCraver: After the downvote my rep increaded from 6017 to 6019. A few minutes later the downvoter removed the vote. After that I triggered a recalc and the rep got back to 6017.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This happened because [the post in question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10006171/error-column-count-doesnt-match-value-count-at-row-1) was deleted then undeleted.  When either of these happens we sync up rep within 5 minutes...you simply did not wait 5 minutes.

Timeline:

- **2012-04-04 06:51:47Z** Post was downvoted (-2)
- **2012-04-04 06:52:34Z** Post was deleted
- **2012-04-04 06:53:37Z** Rep sync performed (+2)
- **2012-04-04 06:54:29Z** Post was undeleted
- **2012-04-04 06:55:24Z** Post was undownvoted (+2 - not correct, that's why we perform a sync)
- **2012-04-04 06:57:52Z** *You triggered a rep recalc* (-2)
- **2012-04-04 06:58:35Z** The system *would* have done the same -2 adjustment

Everything is working as it should here, you simply didn't wait for the 5 minute time period, which is how often we process these sync batches.