# I've got +12 rep for undelete even when no downvote has been removed yet

Tags: support, reputation, voting, down-votes, deleted-answers

I've posted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19231876/1168156) and I've got a downvote since at first I quoted irrelevant part of standard, yet I've also got 2 upvotes, so with score 1 (+2/-1) I deleted my answer, edited it and when it was finally correct
I undeleted it ~> downvote was removed and I've got one more upvote.

The reputation log shows: -2, +12, +2 ~> i.e. +14 rep for answer with 3 upvotes & 0 downvotes:

[image]

In this question, someone was experiencing similar problem: [Got 2 plus points from downvote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/128071/178691) but I guess it was different.

Is this bug? What I am missing here?

Comment: Someone removed their downvote on your question, so you got the 2 reputation back

Comment: @RichardTingle: But why I've got additional +2 today?

Comment: because -2 + (+2) =0

Comment: @RichardTingle: I think the system gave me 2 rep back by the time I've got +12

Comment: You hit the rep cap and only got 12 instead of 20 points.

Comment: @juergend: Why I've received 30 rep for another answer afterwards?

Comment: @LihO - You didn't. The 30 is from before hitting the rep cap. You got additional upvotes on that answer _afterwards_, but no reputation.

Comment: argh was about to answer! :-)

Comment: @Sklivvz: Then do :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason why you don't simply have +30 for the three upvotes and have +12 instead is that you reached the reputation cap.

The second +2 vote is due to a downvote being reversed (thus undoing the -2).[image]

More in depth, the reputation timeline shows a rolled-up summary of rep changes per question. In your case you had a fourth upvote on the "How to +1" question at 19:03, which gave you 0 rep to the rep cap, but changed the timestamp of the roll-up to that time.

Comment: Shouldn't the system show that "+12" later than "+30" in this case?

Comment: That's because this is showing a roll up. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Aggregating rep change per question is wise and practical, yet I think it shouldn't happen in this case. The "+12" should have a proper timestamp reflecting the event at the moment it really occured.

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/users/1168156/liho?tab=reputation&sort=post

Comment: Yeah, it shows all events perfectly. Thank you ^^